# GLKit vs. Metal perspective matrix difference

Tags: swift, opengl, 3d, metal, glkit

I'm reading a Metal [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/137398/ios-metal-tutorial-swift-part-5-switching-metalkit) on raywenderlich.com, where it introduces a pure Swift float4x4 [helper class](https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2016/09/Metal_5_swift3_resources.zip). 99% it's just wrapper around GLKit functions, except one function which really puzzles me:

```
  static func makePerspectiveViewAngle(_ fovyRadians: Float, aspectRatio: Float, nearZ: Float, farZ: Float) -> float4x4 {
    var q = unsafeBitCast(GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(fovyRadians, aspectRatio, nearZ, farZ), to: float4x4.self)
    let zs = farZ / (nearZ - farZ)
    q[2][2] = zs
    q[3][2] = zs * nearZ
    return q
  }
```

Why does it need to change `q[2][2]` and `q[3][2]`. Is this some incompatibility between Metal's and GLKit's coordinate system?

Is this a particular choice this tutorial made? If not, are there any other incompatibilities between GLKit and Metal mathematics?

---

**Update**: I found a nice illustration about Metal's clip space coordinate system from the WWDC 2016 Session: Adopting Metal I.

[image: clip-space]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from [this forum question](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/ios-metal-tutorial-with-swift-part-5-switching-to-metalkit/19283)

> OpenGL uses different clip-space coordinates than Metal (in GL, z goes
>   from -1 to 1, while in Metal z goes from 0 to 1), so using
>   GLKMatrix4MakePerspective doesn't give you a matrix that properly
>   transforms from eye space to clip space. Instead, it transforms half
>   of the viewing volume behind the eye, causing sometimes-subtle
>   clipping and culling issues. You can fix up the matrix you get back
>   from GLK by setting the matrix elements that are relevant to depth by
>   adding the following code to makePerspectiveViewAngle:
>
> let zs = farZ / (nearZ - farZ)
>
> q[2][2] = zs
>
> q[3][2] = zs * nearZ

Comment: Also there is a nice visual explanation from a WWDC video, added it to my question.